# Целочисленные литералы

Tags: java

Скажите, почему, если написать:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  long i = 0xa;
    System.out.print(i);
```

то выводится 10. А если так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  long i = 0xba;
    System.out.print(i);
```

то выводится 186? Короче говоря, объясните, как работает присвоение значения переменной таким способом записи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что `0x` значит, что число будет записано в шестнадцатиричной системе счисления.

Если вы откроете любой конвертер числа с 16-тиричной системы в 10-ричную ([например тут](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/RU/units-converter/numbers/4-3/)) и введете `ba` то увидите результат: `186`

`a` - это число десять в 16-тиричной системе:

```html
0 - 0
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 3
4 - 4
5 - 5
6 - 6
7 - 7
8 - 8
9 - 9 
a - 10
b - 11
c - 12
d - 13
e - 14
f - 15
```

Отсюда и соответствующий результат.

Перевод из 16 в 10 осуществляется по базовым правилам:

```html
Для перевода шестнадцатеричного числа в десятичное необходимо это число представить 
в виде суммы произведений степеней основания шестнадцатеричной системы счисления
 на соответствующие цифры в разрядах шестнадцатеричного числа.

Например, требуется перевести шестнадцатеричное число BA в десятичное. 
В этом числе 2 разряда. Разряды считаются, начиная с нулевого, 
которому соответствует младший бит (крайний правый).  

В соответствии с вышеуказанным правилом представим его 
в виде суммы степеней с основанием 16:  

BA = (11 * 16^1) + (10 * 16^0) = 11 * 16 + 10 = 176 + 10 = 186
```

Comment: Нет, я понимаю, но скажите принцип этого переопределения.

Comment: @МиронФисенко т.е. как переводится система счисления в другую?

Comment: Да, именно это.

Comment: @МиронФисенко я конечно описал, но это как бы основы программирования,